# Reflection and NullPointerException with static fields/methods?

Tags: java, reflection, static, instance

I am trying to use reflection to access a method and variable that I do not want inherited by an object. I receive a null pointer exception with these *static* variables, and I cannot notice anything I have missed. I would appreciate help in resolving the exception :)

Am I missing any lines, or not using Alien.class when I need to?

Main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Starting process of alien creation...");
    Alien alien_1 = new Alien("Bob", 5, (float) 45.3, AlienType.REACTIVE);
    Alien alien_2 = new Alien("Lilly", 7, (float) 49.8, AlienType.FRIENDLY);
    System.out.println("\n" + alien_1.getName());
    alien_1.setName("Carl");
    System.out.println(alien_1.getName());
    Method getNameList = null;
    Field nameList = null;
    try {
        getNameList = Alien.class.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getNameList");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Method \"getNameList\" does not exist!");
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Method \"getNameList\" cannot be used!");
    }

    try {
        nameList = Alien.class.getClass().getDeclaredField("alienNames");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Field \"nameList\" does not exist!");
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Field \"nameList\" cannot be used!");
    }

    getNameList.setAccessible(true);
    nameList.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        ArrayList<String> returnValue = (ArrayList<String>) getNameList.invoke(new Alien(), nameList);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Alien class:

```
public class Alien 
{
    public void getAndPrintType(AlienType type)
    {
        switch (type) 
        {
            case FRIENDLY : System.out.print(", type - FRIENDLY.\n"); break;
            case SCARY : System.out.print(", type - SCARY.\n"); break;
            case REACTIVE : System.out.print(", type - REACTIVE.\n"); break;
        }
    }

    String name;
    int age;
    float weight;
    AlienType type;

    int totalAliens;

    public static ArrayList<String> alienNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> alienAges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Float> alienWeights = new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList<AlienType> alienTypes = new ArrayList<AlienType>();

    float totalWeight;

    public Alien(String name, int age, float weight, AlienType type)
    {
        System.out.print("You have created an alien of attributes: ");
        System.out.print("name - " + name );
        System.out.print(", age - " + String.valueOf(age));
        System.out.print(", weight - " + String.valueOf(weight) + " pounds");
        getAndPrintType(type);
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.type = type;

        // Global impact
        totalAliens++;
        alienNames.add(name);
        alienAges.add(age);
        alienWeights.add(weight);
        alienTypes.add(type);
    }

    public Alien() {}
    private static String getNameList()
    {
        String returnValue = "";
        for (String nameLocal : alienNames)
        {
            if (!(alienNames.get((alienNames.size() - 1)).equals(nameLocal)))
            {
                returnValue += nameLocal + ", ";
            }
            else
            {
                returnValue += nameLocal;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can edit your question. Please add the full stack trace. What is the relevance of all the code you've posted. Please shorten it to only the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be at this line:

```
getNameList = Alien.class.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getNameList");
```

`Alien.class` becomes a reference to `Class<Alien>`, so `getClass` returns the runtime class of `Class<Alien>` which is `Class.class`. You then call `getDeclaredMethod` on the reference to `Class.class`, looking for the method named `getNameList` which unsurprisingly does not exist in the `Class` class, and the `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown, and `getNameList` remains null.

Knowing all this, the solution is to remove the call to `getClass` so you're calling `getDeclaredMethod` on the reference to `Class<Alien>`:

```
getNameList = Alien.class.getDeclaredMethod("getNameList");
```

Comment: Excellent description, you gave me example but explained every individual part of it :) Thank you!

Comment: @TheeNinjaDev welcome to StackOverflow. If the answer answered your question please check it.